# How to set color to Java JCSG object? [JavaFX]

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-3d

I'm currently using the Java JCSG library to create Constructive Solid Geometry objects such as intersections, unions and difference between 3D objects. Using the [JCSG library](https://github.com/miho/JCSG), I have the following code for creating objects (cube in this case)

```
private static CSG createCube(double w, double h, double d) {
            return new Cube(w, h, d).toCSG();
}
```

and whenever I want to set the colour of this specific CSG object I use the following

```
private static CSG color(CSG shape, Color c) {
            return shape.color(c);
}
```

However when I transform these objects to a MeshView and pass them to the javafx.scene.Group the color is the default one (red):

```
        Group world = new Group();
        System.out.println(this.objects.size());
        for (CSG p : this.objects) {
            var x = p.toJavaFXMesh().getAsMeshViews().get(0);

            for(Material m: p.toJavaFXMesh().getMaterials()){
                System.out.println(m.toString());

                // System.out.println(m1.getDiffuseColor().toString());
                x.setMaterial((PhongMaterial)m);
            }
            world.getChildren().add(x);
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(world, WIDTH, HEIGHT, true);
        scene.setFill(Color.PALETURQUOISE);
        scene.setCamera(camera);

        // initMouseControl(world, scene, primaryStage);
        addEventHandlers(scene, camera);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Pane");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
```

Where `this.objects` holds all the objects that I created in another class.

```
package me.emil;

import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import me.emil.helpers.Pane;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CSGStorage singleton = CSGStorage.getInstance();
        var x = singleton.sphere(50);
        x = singleton.translate(x, 100, 0, 0);
        x = singleton.color(x, Color.YELLOW);
        singleton.addPrimitive(x);

        Pane p = new Pane();
        p.launchPane();
    }
}
```

Comment: When you use `toJavaFXMesh()`, a `MeshContainer` object is created, with [`RED` diffuse color](https://github.com/miho/JCSG/blob/master/src/main/java/eu/mihosoft/jcsg/MeshContainer.java#L52), so the initial material configuration is lost. You will need to apply it afterwards, i.e. `x.setMaterial(new PhongMaterial(Color.YELLOW));`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Is there any other way I can pass CSG objects to the `Group` so I do not lose the initial material configuration?

Comment: Not sure, maybe via exporting to stl/obj and then importing the model, but will require importers...